# Gapp on Cyanogen 13 not working

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms, oppo-find-7

First of all, sorry about this question, there are loads already out there, but unfortunately none have fixed my issue, or at least I haven't been able to fix it.

So I have a Oppo find 7, I followed the `theunlockr` tutorial to root my phone, install a new rom (cyanogen) and gapp.
After struggling a lot (first time I did this kind of thing), I finally managed to back up my colorOs with my old data, wype data, flash the new rom. So far so good, but I don't have play store to install anything, or sync my account.

So I downloaded Gapp, followed the indication, flashed it, restarted, but always had loads on `Unfortunately, Google ... has stopped`

I have read quite a lot of options to fix this issue but none of them have worked so far. So here is what I have tried:

- reformat everything, install cyanogen, install gapp, restart
- reformat everything, install cyanogen, clear cache, install gapp, clear cache, restart
- reformat everything, install cyaogen, restart, start android, turn off, install gapp from recovery mode, restart

(Tried for both nightly and latest release)

I have read somewhere that I needed to grant authorisation to com.android... from my pc, tried that with no success

According to the website I used (https://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=find7 and https://devs-lab.com/android-gapps-download.html), I am using the latest versions of cyanogen and gapp. I also made sure I am using gapp for android 6 and 32 bit device.

Can anyone see anything obvious that I have missed ? I must have tried starting from scratch flashing cyanogen and gapp since yesterday, but maybe I am missing something obvious that I can't see !
Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: as an alternative, as Cyanogen on its own seems to be working, I am open to any alternatives to install google play, but I am not sure there is any...

Answer (score 0):

LOL i went thru this few weeks ago put cyanogenmod and gapps on the sd wipe your system,data,boot . flash cm13 then gapps then in twrp if you have it if not flash itdo a factory reset. that will remove the gapps issues boot into cm13 and all should be good